# Chrome Show CACHE images and html

Tags: file, google-chrome, caching

last week I accessed a page which is no longer available. But it is still in my cache.
My problem: I found the cache-folder on my mac - located at users/YOUR USERNAME/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache

But inside this folder are files like: 0a0b277541864b7c_0
- so not the html-filename or image-filename. 
How can I see these files - look for the index.html and view the page out of my cache?
How can I transfer this file to that what is usually was - e.g. a jpg or html-file?

That sucks. In the past on IE I just went to the cache folder and all files were there and viewable.

thanks for your help.